# TCL comparing two fields in a file and printing the line

Tags: tcl

I have two files.

- **File a**

> 0 10 20 30
>
> 10 20 30 40
>
> 0 10 23 34

**Values of File a are in (x1 y1 x2 y2 format)**

- **File b**
- format is P M M x y -(some number)

> P M M 10 20 -100
>
> P M M 20 30 -150
>
> P M M 50 60 -100

in File B, I want to search if field 4,5(starting from P as field 1) is in range in File a. If it is then dont print the line of FileB else print the line.

we will not print line of File b where

> x1 < x < x2 & y1 < y < y2

so the O/P of the script should be

**File c**

> P M M 50 60 -100

---

I have written the following script in tcl but my issue is that it is **not searching for all the content of file b in File a**.

---

```
set abc "b"
set ab "a"

set cord [open $ab "r"]

if [catch {open $abc r} FILE_R {
    puts "failed to read $abc"
    return -1
}

while { [gets $FILE_R line] >= 0 } {
    if [regexp {^#} $line ] {
    } else {
        set x_cord [lindex $line 3] 
        set y_cord [lindex $line 4]
        while { [gets $cord line] >= 0 } {
            set x1_cord [lindex $line 0]
            set y1_cord [lindex $line 1]
            set x2_cord [lindex $line 2]
            set y2_cord [lindex $line 3]

            if { [expr x1_cord < x_cord && x_cord < x2_cord && y1_cord < y_cord && y_cord < y2_cord ] == 1 } {
            } else {
                puts $line
            }
        }
    }
}

close $FILE_R
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if { [expr x1_cord < x_cord && x_cord < x2_cord && y1_cord < y_cord && y_cord < y2_cord ] == 1 } {
```

is rather wrong in a number if respects. In particular, those variables are not being read from. You're also doing extra work by putting `expr` inside an `if` condition, as they already use the same syntax. Instead, use this:

```
if {$x1_cord < $x_cord && $x_cord < $x2_cord && $y1_cord < $y_cord && $y_cord < $y2_cord} {
```

You also seem to be using `if {somecondition} {} else { somescript }`; that's not especially inefficient, but it looks strange. Just negate the condition and do it like this: `if {!(somecondition)} { somescript }`

Comment: Hi--> Im not able to recursively go through the complete "file b" it only picks teh first line from the file and tries to seacrh it in the file a. I need to search each line of file b in a.

Answer (score 0):

First open the file of coordinates and read each line until you have the maximum and minimum values for each of x1,y1,x2,y2. That will be 8 values.

Then open the second file and read each line once. Then split it and compare it with your limits.

The problem you have above is you open each file once but you are attempting to re-read the coord file each time you have a FILE_R line. But you never seek back to the start of the file. If you did, it would be hugely inefficient but might work. Get the limits first then process the second file.

It is also smarter to match lines with regexp but split them with scan. This way you are less likely to run into problems with things Tcl considers significant like open braces or semicolons or excessive numbers of spaces. For instance:

```
% scan "P M M 10 20 -100" {P M M %d %d %d} x y z
3
% list $x $y $z
10 20 -100
```

Notice we can check we got the right number of scanned parameters (3).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comments but Im not comparing against minimum & maximum values. Both my files are having radom numbers. What Im interested is printing only those lines of file b which are out of range against a set of x1,y1,x2,y2. The "file a" actually contains  boxes and Im looking for point lying outside those boxes. Taking minimum & maximum value may not sove what Im looking for. Can you please help correct my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
package require Tclx

# Read file a.txt, which contains x1 y1 x2 y2
# After reading, coords will be
#     {{0 10 20 30} {10 20 30 40} {0 10 23 34}}
# which is a list of lists
set coords [split [read_file a.txt] \n]

# Read file b.txt, line by line
# where each line contains P M M x y -(some number)
for_file line b.txt {
    if {[regexp {^#} $line]} { continue }; # skip comment

    #lassign    $line p m1 m2 x y n; # parse the line into proper fields
    foreach {p m1 m2 x y n} $line {}; 
    set inrange 0; # assume out of range, will flag it if found otherwise
    foreach coord $coords {
        #lassign $coord x1 y1 x2 y2; # parse the range
            foreach {x1 y1 x2 y2} $coord {}
        if {$x1 < $x && $x < $x2 && $y1 < $y && $y < $y2} {
            set inrange 1; # we are in range, set the flag for not printing
        }
    }

    # Print if not in any range
    if {!$inrange} { puts $line }
}
```

#### Discussion

- The commands `read_file`, `for_file`, and `lassign` comes from the `Tclx` package, which simplify life quite a bit. The `lassign` becomes a built-in command starting with Tcl version 8.5.
- To answer the comment: you can use `read_file` as long as you use the `Tclx` package. It does not matter if you have Tcl 8.4, 8.5, or beyond.
- The rest of the code is straight-forward, I hope you don't have trouble understanding.
- Since user2095095 does not have access to `Tclx` and he/she is running Tcl 8.4, I have to replace `lassign` with the `foreach` trick.

Comment: can you please tell me the equivalent command for read_file,for_file in tcl 8.5

Comment: A quick-and-dirty substitute for `[read_file a.txt]` in plain Tcl is just `[read [open a.txt]]`.  This leaks the file handle but that's not serious unless you call this lots of times.

Comment: `for_file` is just equivalent to your original code to open FILE_R, loop over lines read from the file and then close it.

Comment: I dont have 8.5 tclx. What is the equivalent command of lassign in 8.4 version?

Comment: My solution works with Tcl 8.4, and Tclx 8.4. Go ahead and try it out.

Comment: I tried "lassign" is not a recognized keyword. Please give me a similar feature in TCL 8.4

Comment: Did you forget to include `package require Tclx`? The `Tclx` package will give you `lassign`.

Comment: I dont have TCLX & TCL 8.5 ro above. All I have is TCL 8.4..most of the EDA tools have TCL version as 8.4 only. As 8.5 consumes more memory compared to 8.4(The tool developers told me)